# Hide macOS Focus / Sleep notifications in Notification Center and on Lock Sceen

Tags: macos, notifications, monterey, lockscreen, focus

Every time I open my Mac in the morning, I see the notification on my macOS Lock Screen:

[image: Sleep Off Notification]

> Sleep
> Off

When I get home from the gym and open my Mac, I see

> Fitness
> Off

How can I hide this notification? Either completely, or, especially, hide it from the lock screen?

`System Preferences > Notifications & Focus > Notifications` does not have an app section for "Focus" or "Sleep". I cannot find the app to uncheck the normal "Show notifications on lock screen" option.

The `Focus` tab does not seem to have any controls to control notifications for Focus modes.

This is the new Focus feature in macOS 12 Monterey.

Comment: What version of macOS?

Comment: @SteveChambers Monterey

Comment: @pkamb Thanks for this question... On my first morning of Monterey I see the same issue. Not only can I find no way to disable the these, but the behavior is different from iOS devices which don't (usually) display previous Focus state changes.

Answer (score 5):

In the focus tab you can unselect `Share Across Devices` and then disable focus on the Mac completely. Seems to be the only way to “switch off” the notifications. It’s crazy that they forgot to add the option to hide the notification on a feature which is supposed to help you focussing.

On the other hand, focus on the Mac is unnecessary for me I’ve switched of most notifications anyway, so nothing lost.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @Ferio. Agree completely: seems crazy that Apple shipped this silly behavior. I imagine the root cause is differences in either the Notification framework or Sleep states between macOS and iOS. Recommend: https://www.apple.com/feedback